# What is the maximum size of a csv file?

Tags: python, excel, windows, csv, file

I have 70 files in format with an actual file size of 800 MB each. Total original file size: 56000 MB.
Unzipping, moving, and processing (at least renaming the files) become quite challenging and time-consuming tasks in Windows i7.
I was considering if it will be a good idea to concatenate all the files in one file. So, one giant file of size of 56000 MB.

Is there any limitation on the maximum size a CSV file can have? Also, is it a good idea to work with a such big single file or shall I continue with 70 separate files?

Comment: If the files are that large you may want to consider programs other than Excel, we built the small test version on Excel then ported the code to other programs.

Answer (score 1):

The only limitation is your storage limit, in theory a csv can be of unlimited size.

But if it's to big it may be unusable for practical use because limitations of your read and write speed, memory size and so on

Comment: This adds little compared to the first answer posted.

Comment: Except that it probably isn't ChatGPT unlike the other answer...